# Setup Cassandra for Django - "ImportError: No module named pycassa"

Tags: java, django, cassandra, virtualenv, pycassa

I've followed this guide: https://github.com/ericflo/twissandra

Pycassa has been installed including all the dependencies. everything running smoothly, but running `python manage.py sync_cassandra` give message:

```
ImportError: No module named pycassa
```

So I running Python interactive interpreter and typing `import pycassa` and that command runs successfully, with no errors.

Running

```
import sys
sys.path
```

will give message:

```
['', '/home/z/twiss/lib/python2.6/site-packages/setuptools-0.6c11-py2.6.egg', '/home/z/twiss/lib/python2.6/site-packages/pip-0.8.2-py2.6.egg', '/home/z/twiss/lib/python2.6', '/home/z/twiss/lib/python2.6/plat-linux2', '/home/z/twiss/lib/python2.6/lib-tk', '/home/z/twiss/lib/python2.6/lib-old', '/home/z/twiss/lib/python2.6/lib-dynload', '/usr/lib/python2.6', '/usr/lib/python2.6/plat-linux2', '/usr/lib/python2.6/lib-tk', '/home/z/twiss/lib/python2.6/site-packages', '/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/pycassa-1.0.5-py2.6.egg', '/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/virtualenv-1.5.1-py2.6.egg', '/usr/local/lib/python2.6/site-packages', '/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages', '/usr/lib/python2.6/dist-packages', '/usr/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/PIL', '/usr/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/gst-0.10', '/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.6', '/usr/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/gtk-2.0', '/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.6/gtk-2.0']
```

the `site-packages` is in the list. but I a bit confused because this is in virtual environment

I dont know what happened and what to do

Comment: Does it work in the Django REPL?

Comment: I dont know what is Django REPL. I will looking at it

Answer (score 2):

Try editing tweets/management/commands/sync_cassandra.py to include

```
import sys
print sys.path
```

at the top.  Make sure this includes the directory that pycassa is in.  For example, I have a pycassa directory in twiss/lib/python2.6/site-packages.

By the way, ericflo's repo is out of date -- you'll want to use [this version](https://github.com/thobbs/twissandra) until he accepts some pull requests.

Answer (score 0):

Probably pycassa package is missing, I would try the following and also recommend storing the necessary packages in a requirements file and leverage freeze/install like this.

**To solve the first issue with pycassa error:**

> ```
> pip install pycassa
> ```
>
> [image]

Once all the requirements are in for your python project, output the required packages into requirements.txt like the package.json for NodeJS.

- freeze: output current packages into the requirements.txt file
- Install: install every needed packages from the requirements.txt into Python environment

> ```
> pip freeze > requirements.txt
> pip install -r requirements.txt
> ```